# Error: Unexpected request: GET undefined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am writing a jasmine test for my Listservice (unit testing).  but when I call getList method in that service, it is showing Undefined in place of baseUrl.This Listservice is depending on another service i.e., Catalogservice. I think , I did something wrong here.help me

**This is the error**

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET undefined/patients
```

**Service.js:**

```
workerServices.factory('ListService',

['$resource','Restangular','$q','$rootScope','$filter','$location','$state',

    function($resource, Restangular, $q, $rootScope, $filter,$location,$state) {
        return {
            getList: function(baseUrl, resource, searchString,query) {
                var listItems = $q.defer();
                Restangular.setBaseUrl($rootScope.baseUrl);               
                var queryString = '';              
                if (searchString == 'undefined' || searchString == null) 
                {
                    queryString = resource;

                }
                else{
                    queryString = resource + '?' + searchString;
                }

                Restangular.all(queryString).getList().then(function(data) {

                    if (query == 'undefined' || query == null ){
                        listItems.resolve(data);
                    }
                    },
                   function(response){
                    if(response.status != 200){
                        alert("Server is down.Please try after some time");
                        listItems.reject();
                    }
                });
                return listItems.promise;
            }
       }]);
```

**ServiceSpec.js:**

```
describe('Services', function() {

     beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));
   beforeEach(angular.mock.module('workerServices'));

      var scope, service, httpBackend,Restangular,promise1,promise,q;

   beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($httpBackend, $rootScope, ListService,_Restangular_,$q) {
   httpBackend = $httpBackend;
   scope = $rootScope.$new();
   Restangular = _Restangular_;
   service = ListService;
   q = $q;
   }));

   it('reading Listservice data from ListViewController', function() {
   httpBackend.expectGET('/././rest').respond('[{"id":258,"title":"Mr","firstName":"Johnson"}]');
           promise = service.getList('', 'patients', null, null);
           scope.$digest();
           httpBackend.flush();
           console.log(scope.resource['patients'].id);
      });     
});

Thank you.
```